# Unable to get the count 0 , if there are no matched rows from a table- Oracle DB

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get Count and few other columns along with the count.
The below query is working if there is a match but if there are no matches, it is not returning the count with '0'.
The below query is working for matched condition in descending order.
The same(it should return a row in date descending order)wanted to have if there is no match.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select  COUNT(*)  COUNT, col1, col2, col3, col4
      from table
     GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4
      ORDER BY DATE(col4) desc)T 
where col2=value 
AND col3=value 
AND ROWNUM =1
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4955425)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get data in your output even when there is no matching data in the table, you should probably be thinking `LEFT JOIN`.

This query would do it.  It will ensure that you get a row with your search conditions even if there is no match in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM (
WITH search_values AS ( SELECT 'col2_value_you_want' col2_value, 'col3_value_you_want' col3_value FROM DUAL )
select  COUNT(yt.some_non_null_column)  CNT, yt.col1, sv.col2_value col2, sv.col3_value col3, yt.col4
from    search_values sv LEFT JOIN your_table yt ON yt.col2 = sv.col2_value and y2.col3 = sv.col3_value
GROUP BY yt.col1, sv.col2_value, sv.col3_value, yt.col4
ORDER BY DATE(yt.col4) desc
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

In the two queries below, the same concept is applied using `DBA_OBJECTS`, for people you don't have your data model.  The 1st example uses conditions that have a match; the 2nd example uses conditions that do not have a match.

```
SELECT * FROM (
WITH search_values AS ( SELECT 'SYS' owner, 'TABLE' object_type FROM DUAL )
select  COUNT(yt.object_id)  CNT, yt.object_id, sv.owner, sv.object_type, yt.last_ddl_time
from    search_values sv LEFT JOIN dba_objects yt ON yt.owner = sv.owner and yt.object_type = sv.object_type
GROUP BY yt.object_id, sv.owner, sv.object_type, yt.last_ddl_time
ORDER BY yt.last_ddl_time desc
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

... and ...

```
SELECT * FROM (
WITH search_values AS ( SELECT 'NOT_A_USER' owner, 'TABLE' object_type FROM DUAL )
select  COUNT(yt.object_id)  CNT, yt.object_id, sv.owner, sv.object_type, yt.last_ddl_time
from    search_values sv LEFT JOIN dba_objects yt ON yt.owner = sv.owner and yt.object_type = sv.object_type
GROUP BY yt.object_id, sv.owner, sv.object_type, yt.last_ddl_time
ORDER BY yt.last_ddl_time desc
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: I am trying with the first query and not understanding on 'col2_value_you_want' and 'col3_value_you_want'...

Comment: Here i am not sure want you want me to pass for 'col2_value_you_want' but i am gettig col2_value  , as you mentioned in the query 'col2_value_you_want' col2_value

Comment: Whatever you used for `value` in your original query.  E.g., you had: "WHERE ... col2=value AND col3=value".  The first "value" would be what I called "col2_value_you_want".

Comment: Thanks Mathhew. I understood ur query and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks.  Please consider accepting my answer so others know the question is resolved.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - sometimes a left join can't be avoided, but in this case all is needed is to "union all" with just one more row, and take max() over two rows. Really no need for a join here.

Comment: That's reasonable.  I have a slight preference for my answer, however.  If you want the "0 count" row to have the `col2` and `col3` values to which the count of 0 applies, then those values would have to be duplicated in the `UNION ALL` part.  Also, my approach lends itself to other aggregates, like `SUM()` or `MIN()` or whatever, where you might not want 0 in the extra row, or, if you do, you cannot count on the extra row being higher or lower than an actual answer.

Comment: Matthew, is there any tag to set it as resolved/answered or just want me to add the comment to say it is resolved?. i don't see any such tag

Comment: You select the answer that you feel best answers your question, and optionally upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you use `val2` and `val3` in your query (for filtering on `col2` and `col3`) and there are no matches, then the query will return no rows. Where do you want it to put the count of 0? What should it show in `col1, col2, col3, col4`?

I think I understand what you want (which is a very unusual requirement by the way) - if there are no matches, you want to return just one row, with 0 for `COUNT` and `null` for `col1, col2, col3, col4` (or perhaps you want `val2` for `col2` and `val3` for `col3`?) You can do that easily (and you don't need a join), something like this... it adds a little bit to your existing query.

```
SELECT max(COUNT) as COUNT, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3,
       max(col4) as col4
FROM (
         SELECT * 
         FROM (select  COUNT(*)  COUNT, col1, col2, col3, col4
               from table
               GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4
               ORDER BY DATE(col4) desc)T 
         where col2=value 
         AND col3=value 
         AND ROWNUM =1

       UNION ALL

         SELECT 0, null, null, null, null FROM dual
     )
```